# How to get a good picture of pet fish?

Tags: aquarium, fish

It is often important to include a photo of your fish in your question. Based on some of the photos that have been provided this is not always easy.

What are the steps to get a clear, good quality photo of a fish?

Comment: Related: [How do I photograph small fish in a fish tank?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17044/how-do-i-photograph-small-fish-in-a-fish-tank) (photo.SE)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is just pure luck! A lot of times it is patience or bribing them with a treat, luring them with a mirror, end of a pen, pencil eraser and so on. The best method that many breeders, friends, professionals and hobbyist alike tho, are taking videos and screenshotting moments in that video :) I hope this helps!